# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

I am getting the following message in android `LogCat`

```
03-20 01:45:03.362: WARN/System.err(369): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/LazyList/-2012431329 (No such file or directory)
03-20 01:45:03.362: WARN/System.err(369):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
03-20 01:45:03.372: WARN/System.err(369):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
03-20 01:45:03.382: WARN/System.err(369):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
03-20 01:45:03.382: WARN/System.err(369):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
03-20 01:45:03.392: WARN/System.err(369):     at com.ImageLoaders.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:86)
```

For downloading images in android emulator
I have added internet permission in androidManifest.xml file, but looks like it is not working.
I have also given 10MB space to android emulator as well.

any one guide me what could be the problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a file with called `/mnt/sdcard/LazyList/-2012431329`?

Comment: Try new java.io.File("/mnt/sdcard/LazyList/-2012431329").exists(); Does it say true or false?

Comment: This problem has already been solved here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36336679/5832032

Answer (score 29):

I solved this problem adding permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

ImageLoader Constructor should be change to this.

```
public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    // Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect
    // the UI performance
    photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "LazyList");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}
```

By default it is like this

```
cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory(), "LazyList");
```

You should change it to

```
cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "LazyList");
```

I solved my problem 100% in android 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to search for the following directory or file:

```
/mnt/sdcard/LazyList/-2012431329
```

This is looking a little bit weird. This file or directory can't be found since it's not a valid name. Are you sure that this is the correct name?