# Programmatically enable storage android

Tags: java, android, path, filepath

I'm trying to travel through the files in the SD card with C++ Android NDK, just for let the user choose a file in his device, I'm using the dirent.h header, and I get the SD path from java with the method `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

When I test it on BlueStacks(on Windows 10) which has Android 4.4.2, the function reads the file names correctly, but when I test it on a Nexus 6p with Android 7 it fails, and it gives me errno = 13, that means:

```
#define EACCES      13  /* Permission denied */
```

On the following post, I could find the reason of why that happens.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36336679/5166295

So, Is there any programmatically way to enable that option?

Is this only while I'm debugging the app, and in the final version (with the APK) this will dissapear?

Or, Is any way to get the raw path and not symlinks?

Or, Do I have to tell my users to enable that option manually?

Comment: Do you have `uses-permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest file?

Comment: yes,  I have both READ and WRITE

Comment: `READ` is useless, since `WRITE` implies `READ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that since Android 6 the permissions changed, so now they have the form of runtime permissions, and you have to ask for the permission when you are going to use it, so it is not enable by default when the app is installed.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/runtime_perms.html

Answer (score 1):

> I get the SD path from java with the method Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` has nothing to do with an SD card on ~2 billion Android devices. That points to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> Is there any programmatically way to enable that option?

Your Java code can [request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). I do not believe that there is a way to request this directly from the NDK.

> Is this only while I'm debugging the app, and in the final version (with the APK) this will dissapear?

No.